# How to change name for button in Preferences?

Tags: java, android

I have made Android application which uses Preferences. I have following layout for prefs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <EditTextPreference 
        android:key="device_id" 
        android:title="Device ID"/>
    <ListPreference 
        android:key="update_time" 
        android:entries="@array/update_keys" 
        android:entryValues="@array/update_values" 
        android:title="Update time"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

When I execute preferences I see 2 hide labels "Device ID" and "Update time", and I need to click by Device ID that to open EditText and input value. How can I set that EditText will be opened automatically, without clicking? Also, when I click by "Update time"(List of radiobuttons) I see "Cancel" button on the bottom of list. How can I change name of button for "Close"?

Answer (score 0):

EditTextPreference is a dialog preference so it will open up in a new window.

Comment: Is there alternative for making field for text?

Comment: You will have to create your own custom preference